# Variants and AssetImage in flutter not working

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

This is my folder structure for the asset my_earth.jpg. This is the code I have used to get the asset

```
DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image:  AssetImage('assets/image/my_earth.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

This is my asset declaration in pubspec.yaml

assets:
    - assets/image/ 
    - assets/video/

Q: Only the main asset is being displayed and not the variants. The main asset has a size of 10x10 and when I ran it in the iPad Simulator , it gave me 10x10. I thought it might select the variants, ( the sizes are as follows : 16x16 --> 1.0x, 20x20 ---> 2.0x, 29x29---> 3.0x etc.). When I used the original 1024x1024, it showed me 1024x1024. I am perplexed as to how utilise this Asset Image Loader and variants for multi device support, ( as ios requires 1x ( deprecated as almost all devices are now Retina supported), 2x , 3x while android requires the 4 formats of images distributed in dbpi folders.

Please assist me to realise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In pubspec.yaml, try adding `assets/image/my_earth.jpg` instead of `assets/image`

Comment: I have added so, and still it shows 10x10, which is the original file instead of the variant

Comment: Are you able to generate the proper link e.g. `AssetImage('assets/$_size/my_earth.jpg')` where _size = '1.0x' ?

Comment: Yes, when I write explicit paths , for instance AssetImage('assets/5.0x/my_earth.jpg'), it gives me the image that is of size 32x32, which is correct

Comment: Have you finally resolve this problem? I have faced the same issue as well..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no out of box provision to specify the assets route based on the OS and device type. With reference to the the answers in the comments, here is the answer :

You'll have to specify the path explicitly. I mean, you'll have to detect the device type, screen size etc and then specify the exact path. For example, in one of my app, I've three json files in the assets directory for language localisation. And based on the user's choice, I point the correct path

```
String jsonContent = await rootBundle
        .loadString("assets/locale/localization_${locale.languageCode}.json");
```

Comment: Here in lies the problem that I have. From the doc https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images , it doesn't mention that we need to explicitly mention the paths. If so, why the need to use AssetImage , when Image.asset is there to do the function?

Comment: It is like how insurance works. You will have to buy it before hand and preserve it with you before using it. The assets have to be declared in  pubspec.yaml and then you can use it whenever you want to use it.